How to Handle a Singularity: Seeking Solutions for a Differential Equation System
I am trying to solve the following differential equation system:
$\begin{aligned} & r^2 K^{\prime \prime}=K(K-1)(K-2)+\frac{1}{4} h^2 K \\ & r^2 h^{\prime \prime}=\frac{1}{2} h K^2+\left(\lambda / g^2\right)\left(h^2-g^2 V_0^2 r^2\right) h\end{aligned}$
I have already tried Rk4 but it does not give me satisfying results (the problem is the singularity at r = 0). And before I try other methods, I wanted to ask if this type of differential equation is known or if it can at least be put into a known form so that I can think of a separate method.
Normally the following procedure should let me solve the system numerically, or not?
$\begin{aligned}\frac{du_1}{dr} &= u_2 \\
\frac{du_2}{dr} &= \frac{u_1(u_1-1)(u_1-2)}{r^2} + \frac{\frac{1}{4}u_3^2 u_1}{r^2} \\
\frac{du_3}{dr} &= u_4 \\
\frac{du_4}{dr} &= \frac{\frac{1}{2}u_1^2u_3 + \left(\frac{\lambda}{g^2}\right)(u_3^2 - g^2V_0^2r^2)u_3}{r^2}\end{aligned}$
with: $\begin{aligned} u_1 &= K  \\
u_2 &= K' = \frac{du_1}{dr} \\
u_3 &= h \\
u_4 &= h' = \frac{du_3}{dr}\end{aligned}$

See MATLAB numerical solution MSE_Q4929562
